# Toolbar to each fragment or Single toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-toolbar

I have a general question about application architecture or UI patterns.

Imaging we are developing an application with a single activity and multiple fragments.
some of the fragments have a toolbar and some of them don't have, some are full screen and some are collapsing toolbar (Telegram or Instagram for example).

In this case of an application which approach is better, have a single toolbar in MainActivity or implement toolbar for each fragment?

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you app is going to look like and do.
If the toolbar won't have much interaction with fragments, then you can put it in the activity. This could also possibly make some animations easier if you will have them.

If the toolbar has very different behavior depending on fragment, then it is better to put it in each fragment since it will simplify your code a lot, you won't have to delegate stuff from activity to the fragment and won't have to deal with state of the toolbar. e.g. when having search bar in some fragments.